# Disadvantage of Mongo rs.slaveOk() for master instances

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am using Robomongo tool to connect to various mongo instances. One blocker I faced was that Robomongo do not allow setting readpreference for the particular connection. 
However, I saw that we can specify Robomongo to load .mongorc.js file at start up. So I added the line `rs.slaveOk()` to it and now I can connect to slave instances as well. 
But this also means that readpreference will be set to secondary even when I am connecting to master instances. I would like to know if there are any disadvantages of keeping this on for all connections. I am sure there is some reason behind Robomongo developers not allowing this as default setting (although setting connection preference for each connection would have been the best solution)

Answer (score -1):

It could be because of stale read issue mentioned here -

[http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#edge-cases-2-primaries]

It requires awareness of your replication strategy and 'staleness' of data. The link above is a great read regardless.

edit: answer lacked a brief summary from MongoDB docs linked above ( as mentioned by user 200-ok)                                        "Exercise care when specifying read preferences: Modes other than primary may return stale data because with asynchronous replication, data in the secondary may not reflect the most recent write operations"

Comment: Yes, all secondary reads will be stale. To be frank the benefit of reading from secondary has serious flaws in it's logic as such normally it is turned off. As fir robomongo not allowing it...dunno

Comment: I do understand it would be stale data. However, apart from this, is there anything problematic? I think they should allow this option in advanced tab with default being from primary. Any change is the user's responsibility for all the consequences

Comment: @NayanjyotiDeka tbh this might just be a preference on the robomongos developer side, it might be worth going to github and asking them why. I see no obvious reason if you understand the problem of stale reads.

Comment: I just found this thread, looks like more of a dev issue than anything -- https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/84